# Android Studio - pushing app to phone, won't let me

Tags: java, android, crash, installation, apk

EDIT: running Windows 8.1

Fully up-to-date Android Studio detects the phone (rooted Samsung Note 3 on 5.1). It's compatible. Developer Mode is active, USB debugging on, etc. Never had a problem connecting the phone for dragging and dropping.

However, whenever I try to put it on the phone...

```
    Installation failed with message null.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application? (YES / NO)
```

No matter whether I press yes or no, I will get the same  error.

```
Target device: samsung-sm_n920t-93eb26a9
Installing APK: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\CopySunshine\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.sdg.copysunshine
Installing com.sdg.copysunshine
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.fox.pac"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.fox.pac
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.fox.pac
```

I can use emulators (like Genymotion) just fine, it's just that having Android Studio / Emulators make my computer run hot at times, so I'd rather not do it if I can...

A solution I've tried is putting "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES." into the Manifest but then I get a message that only system apps have that privilege.

I have another phone, a rooted S4 that running on 4.4.2. but whenever I connect that, the phone's UI crashes completely... that's a whole different issue.

Answer (score 0):

First off, some rooting techniques screw a few things up so it could be that the root caused the problem.

Nonetheless, could you include which OS you are running Android Studio on? 
Did you get the promt to authenticate. Maybe revoke authentocation from the developer options and try again.

I had the same problem one day and I solved it by reinstalling drivers on my computer for the device. Then when I run as administrator I am able to deploy my application without any problems.

Also try to uninstall the app from the command line.

```
~ adb uninstall com.yourpackagename
```

A few other commands to check if everything works:

```
~ adb devices
~ adb install com.yourpackagename
```

Comment: I tried the command menu. I did not previously have the ADB and Command line together. The ADB servers did detect the devices, however attempting to install it gave me the error "Missing APK".

Comment: Did you try manually uninstalling? Also,  you should try the Samsung Kies library.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your reply. I also tried uninstalling, it gave me the same error message as above. Samsung Kies did not work either, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but make sure you have installed Samsung Kies, available here:

http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

Without it you will not be able to run your Android Studio apps on Samsung devices.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, but I did have Samsung Kies 3 installed